# 406 error when responding with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, batman.js

I'm trying to get a rails app running with the node.js framework batman.js via the batman-rails gem.

When I'm responding with json in my rails controller, I get a 406 error everytime, and I don't know why. Here's my controller:

```
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Sample.all
  end
```

This gives me a 406 no matter what. I do not think this is related to batman, but rails itself. But for good measure, here's my batman code:

```
  index: (params) ->
    TopNavTemplate.Sample.load (err) -> throw err if err
    @set 'samples', TopNavTemplate.Sample.get('all')
```

And then my index.html.erb file simply says 'index', it isn't really doing anything with batman yet.

There is a lot of 406 JSON related questions, I haven't really been able to apply them yet to my situation. Is there something I'm doing wrong to make rails respond_with JSON?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Alright, I made a very simple app to check out your situation:

SamplesController.rb

```
class SamplesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with Sample.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    respond_with Sample.all
  end
end
```

When I visited `/samples.json` and `samples/1.json`, it worked as intended. However, when I went to `/samples` and `/samples/1` (no .json extension), I got a 406 error.

In order to have the URL's work without the .json extension, you need to modify your `config/routes.rb` file as follows:

```
resources :samples, defaults: {format: :json}
```

Otherwise, the Rails application will attempt to respond to the request with an HTML response.

Comment: I just want to note for people that see this nowadays that Batman's Rails store adapter now appends .json to all requests by default.