# Receiving 406 error making d3.json call to rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I've got a web page trying to make a request to a rails app for json data using d3. For some reason, I keep getting a 406 error ('Not Acceptable') and within the controller, `request.content_type` is `nil` and `request.format` gives me:

```
#<Mime::Type:0x00000002595c20 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=4164709875014779265>
```

What am I doing wrong?

The JavaScript

```
url = '/sources/data/' + $('#source_id').val() + '/' + $(this).val();
  return d3.json(url, function(d) {
    var color, format, height, pack, svg, width;
    console.log(d);
    //...do some stuff
```

The Controller:

```
class SourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_source

  def get_data
  @count_data = Hash.new
  case params[:type].downcase
  when 'stems'
    @count_data =  JSON.parse @source.stem_cache
  when 'words'
    @count_data =  JSON.parse @source.word_cache
  when 'synonyms'
    @count_data =  JSON.parse @source.synonym_cache
  end
  puts "hello"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: @count_data}
  end
end
```

Comment: please add sample url

Comment: I think you can get answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320259/406-error-when-responding-with-json

Comment: Thanks, @artgb! I'd thought specifying the content_type was enough, but it turns out I needed to add `.json` to the url -- and your direction to re-read that post caused me to experiment and find out this truth. I'd appreciate if you'd post this as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's problem in this line

```
url = '/sources/data/' + $('#source_id').val() + '/' + $(this).val();
```

you have to

add extension 'json' to the url

or change route file

resources :source, defaults: {format: :json}